# Unable to write the query for SQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a complex SQL query. I am almost there but I got stuck.

> **PROBLEM:** Classify orders into **3 different categories**.
>
> **'Regular Order'** - when the order amount is **less than or equal to 10,000**.
>
> **'Not So Expensive Order'** - when the order amount is **less than or equal to 60,000 and greater than 10,000**.
>
> **'Expensive Order'** - when the order amount is **greater than 60,000**.
>
> Print the name of the category in which the orders have been
> categorized into in the first column followed by count of such orders
> in the second column. Sort the result set in descending order of Count
> of orders.

[Database Schema Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsN1A.png)

Query:

```
select distinct IF(Total_order_amount <= 10000, 'Regular Order', 
       IF(Total_order_amount > 60000, 'Expensive Order','Not So Expensive Order') ) AS 'categories' 
 from Orders;
```

Output:

|  | categories |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 1 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 2 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 3 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 4 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 5 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 6 | Expensive Order |
| 7 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 8 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 9 | Regular Order |
| 10 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 11 | Regular Order |
| 12 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 13 | Regular Order |
| 14 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 15 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 16 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 17 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 18 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 19 | Regular Order |
| 20 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 21 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 22 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 23 | Regular Order |
| 24 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 25 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 26 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 27 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 28 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 29 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 30 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 31 | Regular Order |
| 32 | Regular Order |
| 33 | Regular Order |
| 34 | Expensive Order |
| 35 | Regular Order |
| 36 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 37 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 38 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 39 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 40 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 41 | Regular Order |
| 42 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 43 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 44 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 45 | Regular Order |
| 46 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 47 | Not So Expensive Order |
| 48 | Regular Order |
| 49 | Not So Expensive Order |

I am expecting the count column as well.

Comment: "but i stuck" - what does that mean? Do you have any **specific** question about this? If yes, share it, along with the table structure, sample input data, and the expected output

Comment: select distinct IF(Total_order_amount <= 10000, 'Regular Order', 
       IF(Total_order_amount > 60000, 'Expensive Order','Not So Expensive Order') ) AS 'categories' , count(*) as count
 from Orders group by  IF(Total_order_amount <= 10000, 'Regular Order', 
       IF(Total_order_amount > 60000, 'Expensive Order','Not So Expensive Order') );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are missing the count, I think it should work this way:

```
    select IF(Total_order_amount <= 10000, 'Regular Order', 
       IF(Total_order_amount > 60000, 'Expensive Order','Not So Expensive Order') ) AS 'categories' , count(*) as count
 from Orders group by  IF(Total_order_amount <= 10000, 'Regular Order', 
       IF(Total_order_amount > 60000, 'Expensive Order','Not So Expensive Order') );
```

Note that the syntax you used for IF is not general SQL, I tried in sqlServer and it is considered incorrect